# In retrofit call requested after that internet gets off then it jumps to onfailure()..even though call requested call was successfull..

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit, retrofit2, android-internet

I have tried to use retrofit 2.1.0 for my image upload call in multipart. But the issue that i m facing is call is requested so server side the update is done but in the way of response if internet connection gets off it jumps to onFailure() method even though call was successful.Hope you understand my issue here.Please help me to solve this.Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: until the file is fully uploaded and if the internet turns off in the mean time.. onFailure would be called

Comment: @SantanuSur - My call request of upload gets completed successfully but internet gets off on the time of response came from the server.

Comment: How do you do that? off the internet ..if in any case that happens just use try again.. the user will have to upload the same image again

Comment: @SantanuSur - Is it possible that without making any other web service... from application side i can manage..

Answer (score 0):

In case that happens make the user try again..... in the application side send a tag with the file like `presentFileTag` and in the server side ``

```
if(previousFileTag.equals(presentFileTag)
  { 
   if(fileUploaded)
    { 
      //send response file already present or posetive response
     }
    else 
     {  
     //Store the file  
       }
   }
 else
   {
    //Store the file
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that without making any other web service... from application side i can manage..

Comment: No , because you wont be knowing whether the file has properly uploaded or not ...if you want from only app side.. you have to upload the same file again..

Comment: If you dont wanna upload the full file again..just use that checking in the server side..